# Различия в точности sympy vs numpy. Различие значений в несколько раз

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

Работаю с полиномами в sympy. Столкнулся с проблемой некорректной подстановки значений в `sympy` функцию.
В ходе решения большой системы уравнений получаются коэффициенты для полинома 13 степени. Я раньше когда-то использовал функцию `lambdify` для удобной работы с numpy. И вот теперь стоит задача построить график полинома 15 степени по точкам. У меня есть 2 функции, чтобы сделать это:

```
def plot(x_, x_list, function):
    f = lambdify(x_, function, 'numpy')
    y_list = [f(x_i) for x_i in x_list]
    plt.plot(x_list, y_list)

def plot_2(x_, x_list, function):
    y_list = [function.subs(x_, x_i) for x_i in x_list]
    plt.plot(x_list, y_list)
```

Первая использует `lamdify`, вторая просто делает `sympy` подстановку.
Проблема в том, что поведение кардинально различается. Вот пример для полинома:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

plot - синий график

plot_2 - оранжевый

Никак не могу понять, в чём различия между первым и вторым получением значений? Почему во втором случае есть выбросы? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Вот код проекта:
least_squares.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

init_printing()


class LeastSquares:
    @staticmethod
    def create_polinom(x_, x_list, y_list, n):
        # n - порядок полинома
        if len(x_list) != len(y_list):
            return
        x_buffer = [1 for _ in range(len(x_list))]
        y_buffer = [i for i in y_list]

        A = zeros(n + 1)
        b = Matrix([0 for _ in range(n + 1)])

        # последняя строка матрицы A и матрица b
        for j in range(n, -1, -1):
            b[j] = sum(y_buffer)
            A[n, j] = sum(x_buffer)
            x_buffer = [x_buffer[i] * x_list[i] for i in range(len(x_list))]
            y_buffer = [y_buffer[i] * x_list[i] for i in range(len(x_list))]

        # n первых строк матрицы A
        for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
            for j in range(n, 0, -1):
                A[i, j] = A[i + 1, j - 1]
            A[i, 0] = sum(x_buffer)
            x_buffer = [x_buffer[j] * x_list[j] for j in range(len(x_list))]

        print("Matrix A:")
        display(A)
        print("Matrix b:")
        display(b)

        # Решение СЛАУ
        solution = tuple(linsolve((A, b)))[0]
        coefs = [N(i, 5) for i in solution]

        # Формирование многочлена n-ой стпени
        x_current = 1
        res = 0
        for i in range(len(coefs) - 1, -1, -1):
            res += x_current * coefs[i]
            x_current *= x_
        return res, coefs

    @staticmethod
    def split_intervals(x_list, accuracy):
        x_values = []
        for i in range(len(x_list) - 1):
            x_i = x_list[i]
            x_values.append(x_i)
            step = (x_list[i + 1] - x_i) / (accuracy + 1)
            for j in range(1, accuracy + 1):
                x_values.append(x_i + step * j)
        x_values.append(x_list[-1])
        return x_values

    @staticmethod
    def plot(x_, x_list, function):
        f = lambdify(x_, function, 'numpy')
        y_list = [f(x_i) for x_i in x_list]
        plt.plot(x_list, y_list)

    @staticmethod
    def plot_2(x_, x_list, function):
        y_list = [function.subs(x_, x_i) for x_i in x_list]
        plt.plot(x_list, y_list)
```

В Jupyter notebook файле:

```
from least_squares import LeastSquares
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
import pylab
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15.0, 10.0)
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})

init_printing()

var('x')

y_20 = [5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 12, 10, 8, 10, 8, 11, 7, 9, 11, 10, 9, 12, 11, 6]
x_20 = [x_i for x_i in range(1, len(y_20) + 1)]
display(y_20)
display(x_20)
x_list = LeastSquares.split_intervals(x_20, 20)
polinom_13, coeffs = LeastSquares.create_polinom(x, x_20, y_20, 13)
LeastSquares.plot(x, x_list, polinom_13)
LeastSquares.plot_2(x, x_list, polinom_13)
plt.scatter(range(1, len(y_20) + 1), y_20, color='red', s=100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в наивном подходе при расчёте многочленов. SymPy использует длинную арифметику с помощью `mpmath`, поэтому там нет этой проблемы, а `numpy` не использует подобную арифметику, там проблема присутствует. В `numpy` функция `polyval` может вычислить полином по его коэффициентам с определённой точностью.

```
>>> polinom_13.subs(x, 17.5)
-405.644622653723
>>> lambdify(x,  polinom_13)(17.5) # Incorrect
683.6074018144609
>>> np.polyval(coeffs, 17.5)
-405.644622701054
```

Так что, рекомендую использовать её вместо `lambdify`.

`lambdify(x,  horner(polinom_13))` должно работать тоже, но не работает; не знаю почему.